# How to fit a circle to a set of points with a constrained radius?

Tags: c++, opencv, constraints, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have a set of points that represent a small arc of a circle.

The current code fits a circle to these points using linear least-squares:

```
void fit_circle(const std::vector<cv::Point2d> &pnts,cv::Point2d &centre, double &radius)
{
    int cols = 3;
    cv::Mat X( static_cast<int>(pnts.size()), cols, CV_64F );
    cv::Mat Y( static_cast<int>(pnts.size()), 1, CV_64F );
    cv::Mat C;

    if (int(pnts.size()) >= 3 )
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < pnts.size(); i++)
        {
            X.at<double>(static_cast<int>(i),0) = 2 * pnts[i].x;
            X.at<double>(static_cast<int>(i),1) = 2 * pnts[i].y;
            X.at<double>(static_cast<int>(i),2) = -1.0;
            Y.at<double>(static_cast<int>(i),0) = (pnts[i].x * pnts[i].x + pnts[i].y * pnts[i].y);
        }
        cv::solve(X,Y,C,cv::DECOMP_SVD);
    }
    std::vector<double> coefs;
    C.col(0).copyTo(coefs);
    centre.x = coefs[0];
    centre.y = coefs[1];
    radius = sqrt ( coefs[0] * coefs[0] + coefs[1] * coefs[1] - coefs[2] );
}
```

However, **I have a constraint that the radius must be within a certain range**,
i.e. `minRadius <= radius <= maxRadius`.

So the best fitting circle with a radius within that range should be selected, instead of the overall best fit.

**How can I modify the code to add this constraint?**

Comment: You effectifly want to solve such a equation? `a*2*x + b*2*y - 1 = x^2 + y^2`

Comment: What do you want to happen if the fitted radius is outside the limits?

Comment: I want to select the best fit for a circle within the limits, even if it's not the overall best fit.

Answer (score 3):

Use the coordinate equation from

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreis

```
     G: a*x + b*y + c + y^2 + x^2 = 0
     with
     a: -2*xm
     b: -2*ym
     c: ym^2+xm^2-r^2
```

(This exact equation seems not to be mentioned on the english Wikipedia, but the base form is mentioned.)

To get a linear regression differentiate G^2 for a/b/c

Then you get in matrix form

```
           A        B         C      R        R
     G1:  +2*a*x^2 +2*b*x*y  +2*c*x +2*x^3    +2*x*y^2  = 0 
     G2:  +2*a*x*y +2*b*y^2  +2*c*y +2*y^3    +2*x^2*y  = 0
     G3:  +2*a*x   +2*b*y    +2*c   +2*y^2    +2*x^2    = 0
```

This derivied equations can you solve with your points for a/b/c. From a/b/c you can resubstitute to get xm/ym/r. To reject a specific radius, just check for it's limits.

Example:

[image: Example Circle with a partly known circle]

### EDIT: Source

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

#include <vector>
#include <random>

void fit_circle(const std::vector<cv::Point2d> &pnts, cv::Point2d &centre,
                double &radius)
{
    /*
                   A        B         C      R        R
         G1:  +2*a*x^2 +2*b*x*y  +2*c*x +2*x^3    +2*x*y^2  = 0
         G2:  +2*a*x*y +2*b*y^2  +2*c*y +2*y^3    +2*x^2*y  = 0
         G3:  +2*a*x   +2*b*y    +2*c   +2*y^2    +2*x^2    = 0
    */

    static const int rows = 3;
    static const int cols = 3;
    cv::Mat LHS(rows, cols, CV_64F, 0.0);
    cv::Mat RHS(rows, 1, CV_64F, 0.0);
    cv::Mat solution(rows, 1, CV_64F, 0.0);

    if (pnts.size() < 3)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("To less points");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(pnts.size()); i++)
    {
        double x1 = pnts[i].x;
        double x2 = std::pow(pnts[i].x, 2);
        double x3 = std::pow(pnts[i].x, 3);
        double y1 = pnts[i].y;
        double y2 = std::pow(pnts[i].y, 2);
        double y3 = std::pow(pnts[i].y, 3);

        // col 0 = A / col 1 = B / col 2 = C
        // Row 0 = G1
        LHS.at<double>(0, 0) += 2 * x2;
        LHS.at<double>(0, 1) += 2 * x1 * y1;
        LHS.at<double>(0, 2) += 2 * x1;

        RHS.at<double>(0, 0) -= 2 * x3 + 2 * x1 * y2;

        // Row 1 = G2
        LHS.at<double>(1, 0) += 2 * x1 * y1;
        LHS.at<double>(1, 1) += 2 * y2;
        LHS.at<double>(1, 2) += 2 * y1;

        RHS.at<double>(1, 0) -= 2 * y3 + 2 * x2 * y1;

        // Row 2 = G3
        LHS.at<double>(2, 0) += 2 * x1;
        LHS.at<double>(2, 1) += 2 * y1;
        LHS.at<double>(2, 2) += 2;

        RHS.at<double>(2, 0) -= 2 * y2 + 2 * x2;
    }

    cv::solve(LHS, RHS, solution);

    std::vector<double> abc{solution.at<double>(0, 0),
                            solution.at<double>(1, 0),
                            solution.at<double>(2, 0)};

    centre.x = abc[0] / -2.0;
    centre.y = abc[1] / -2.0;
    radius = std::sqrt(
        std::abs(std::pow(centre.x, 2) + std::pow(centre.y, 2) - abc[2]));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-0.5, 0.5);

        // Generate reandom points
        double radius_in = 25;
        double xm_in = 10;
        double ym_in = 20;

        std::vector<cv::Point2d> pnts;
        {
            for (double ang = 0; ang <= 90; ang += 10)
            {
                cv::Point2d p(
                    cos(ang / 180.0 * M_PI) * radius_in + xm_in + dis(gen),
                    sin(ang / 180.0 * M_PI) * radius_in + ym_in + dis(gen));
                pnts.push_back(p);
            }
        }

        cv::Point2d c_out;
        double radius_out = 0;
        fit_circle(pnts, c_out, radius_out);

        double dxm = c_out.x - xm_in;
        double dym = c_out.y - ym_in;
        double dradius = radius_out - radius_in;

        std::cout << "Deltas: " << dxm << " " << dym << " " << dradius
                  << std::endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

This outputs
Deltas: 0.180365 0.190016 -0.231563

---

EDIT: Add source to generate statistic and statistics about the algorithm

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

#include <vector>
#include <random>

void fit_circle(const std::vector<cv::Point2d> &pnts, cv::Point2d &centre,
                double &radius)
{
    /*
                A        B         C      R        R
        G1:  +2*a*x^2 +2*b*x*y  +2*c*x +2*x^3    +2*x*y^2  = 0
        G2:  +2*a*x*y +2*b*y^2  +2*c*y +2*y^3    +2*x^2*y  = 0
        G3:  +2*a*x   +2*b*y    +2*c   +2*y^2    +2*x^2    = 0
    */

    static const int rows = 3;
    static const int cols = 3;
    cv::Mat LHS(rows, cols, CV_64F, 0.0);
    cv::Mat RHS(rows, 1, CV_64F, 0.0);
    cv::Mat solution(rows, 1, CV_64F, 0.0);

    if (pnts.size() < 3)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("To less points");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(pnts.size()); i++)
    {
        double x1 = pnts[i].x;
        double x2 = std::pow(pnts[i].x, 2);
        double x3 = std::pow(pnts[i].x, 3);
        double y1 = pnts[i].y;
        double y2 = std::pow(pnts[i].y, 2);
        double y3 = std::pow(pnts[i].y, 3);

        // col 0 = A / col 1 = B / col 2 = C
        // Row 0 = G1
        LHS.at<double>(0, 0) += 2 * x2;
        LHS.at<double>(0, 1) += 2 * x1 * y1;
        LHS.at<double>(0, 2) += 2 * x1;

        RHS.at<double>(0, 0) -= 2 * x3 + 2 * x1 * y2;

        // Row 1 = G2
        LHS.at<double>(1, 0) += 2 * x1 * y1;
        LHS.at<double>(1, 1) += 2 * y2;
        LHS.at<double>(1, 2) += 2 * y1;

        RHS.at<double>(1, 0) -= 2 * y3 + 2 * x2 * y1;

        // Row 2 = G3
        LHS.at<double>(2, 0) += 2 * x1;
        LHS.at<double>(2, 1) += 2 * y1;
        LHS.at<double>(2, 2) += 2;

        RHS.at<double>(2, 0) -= 2 * y2 + 2 * x2;
    }

    cv::solve(LHS, RHS, solution);

    std::vector<double> abc{solution.at<double>(0, 0),
                            solution.at<double>(1, 0),
                            solution.at<double>(2, 0)};

    centre.x = abc[0] / -2.0;
    centre.y = abc[1] / -2.0;
    radius = std::sqrt(
        std::abs(std::pow(centre.x, 2) + std::pow(centre.y, 2) - abc[2]));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int count = 100;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        count = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    try
    {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> jitter(-0.5, 0.5);
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> pos(-100, 100);

        std::uniform_real_distribution<> w_start(0, 360);
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> w_length(10, 180);
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> rad(10, 180);

        std::cout << "start\tlen\tdelta xm\tdelta ym\tdelta radius" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            // Generate reandom points
            double radius_in = rad(gen);
            double xm_in = pos(gen);
            double ym_in = pos(gen);

            double start = w_start(gen);
            double len = w_length(gen);

            std::vector<cv::Point2d> pnts;
            {
                for (double ang = start; ang <= start + len; ang += 1)
                {
                    cv::Point2d p(
                        cos(ang / 180.0 * M_PI) * radius_in + xm_in + jitter(gen),
                        sin(ang / 180.0 * M_PI) * radius_in + ym_in + jitter(gen));
                    pnts.push_back(p);
                }
            }

            cv::Point2d c_out;
            double radius_out = 0;
            fit_circle(pnts, c_out, radius_out);

            double dxm = c_out.x - xm_in;
            double dym = c_out.y - ym_in;
            double dradius = radius_out - radius_in;

            std::cout << start << "\t" << len << "\t" << dxm << "\t" << dym << "\t" << dradius
                    << std::endl;
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

100000 circles
[image]

Plot was generated:

```
set multiplot layout 3,1 rowsfirst
set yrange [-50:50]
set grid 
plot 'stat.txt' using 2:3 title 'segment-length vs delta x' with points ps 0.1
set yrange [-50:50]
set grid
plot 'stat.txt' using 2:4 title 'segment-length vs delta y' with points ps 0.1
set yrange [-50:50]
set grid
plot 'stat.txt' using 2:5 title 'segment-length vs delta radius' with points ps 0.1
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly implement this/adapt my code to it. Could you  please post some example code or further explain your answer?

Comment: Thanks for updating it. However, it doesn't answer the question of how to select the best fitting circle with the radius constraints. I don't want to just reject the radius if it's not within the limits, I want to find the radius that is.

Comment: This solution finds the circle with the least mean square error. That is the circle that fits best to the given points. Limits mean, when ist outside of the limits, it is not the solution. You could drop random Points and create a Loop around the function that evaluate your constraint. If the radius is ok, accept it.

Comment: I would use something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing around this function.

Comment: "This solution finds the circle with the least mean square error..." I already had a working implementation of this, finding the best fit was not the issue. My question was specifically asking how to find a fit (not necessarily the best) that has a radius in between a specified min/max. I'll look into Simulated Annealing, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I get your problem right. First idea would probably be: use a fit algorithm with constrains. I do not like those very much, though, as they are very time consuming. My approach would be to constrain the radius by replacing it with a function of type `r=r_min+(r_max-r_min)*0.5*(1+tanh(x))` and fitting `x`. So `x` can vary in the whole range of real numbers giving you radii in the given limits. All remains a simple non-linear fit of continuous functions.

As a python example it looks like:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from random import random
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

def boxmuller(x0,sigma):
    u1=random()
    u2=random()
    ll=np.sqrt(-2*np.log(u1))
    z0=ll*np.cos(2*np.pi*u2)
    z1=ll*np.cos(2*np.pi*u2)
    return sigma*z0+x0, sigma*z1+x0

def random_arcpoint(x0,y0, r,f1,f2,s):
    arc=f1+(f2-f1)*random()
    rr,_=boxmuller(r,s)
    return [x0+rr*np.cos(arc),y0+rr*np.sin(arc)]


def residuals(parameters,dataPoint):
    xc,yc,Ri = parameters
    distance = [np.sqrt( (x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2 ) for x,y in dataPoint]
    res = [(Ri-dist)**2 for dist in distance]
    return res


def residualsLim(parameters,dataPoint,rMin,rMax):
    xc,yc,rP = parameters
    Ri=rMin+(rMax-rMin)*0.5*(1+np.tanh(rP))
    distance = [np.sqrt( (x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2 ) for x,y in dataPoint]
    res = [(Ri-dist)**2 for dist in distance]
    return res


def f0(phi,x0,y0,r):
    return [x0+r*np.cos(phi),y0+r*np.sin(phi)]


def f_lim(phi,rMin,rMax,x0,y0,x):
    rr=(rMin+(rMax-rMin)*0.5*(1+np.tanh(x)))
    return [x0+rr*np.cos(phi), y0+rr*np.sin(phi)]


data=np.array([random_arcpoint(2.1,-1.2,11,1.0,3.144,.61) for s in range(200)])

estimate = [0, 0, 10]
bestFitValues_01, ier_01 = optimize.leastsq(residuals, estimate,args=(data))
print bestFitValues_01
bestFitValues_02, ier_02 = optimize.leastsq(residualsLim, estimate,args=(data,2,15))
print bestFitValues_02, 2+(15-2)*0.5*(1+np.tanh(bestFitValues_02[-1]))
bestFitValues_03, ier_03 = optimize.leastsq(residualsLim, estimate,args=(data,2,8))
print bestFitValues_03, 2+(8-2)*0.5*(1+np.tanh(bestFitValues_03[-1]))
bestFitValues_04, ier_04 = optimize.leastsq(residualsLim, estimate,args=(data,14,24))
print bestFitValues_04, 14+(24-14)*0.5*(1+np.tanh(bestFitValues_04[-1]))

pList=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,35)
rList_01=np.array([f0(p,*bestFitValues_01) for p in pList])


rList_02=np.array([f_lim(p,2,15,*bestFitValues_02) for p in pList])
rList_03=np.array([f_lim(p,2,8,*bestFitValues_03) for p in pList])
rList_04=np.array([f_lim(p,14,24,*bestFitValues_04) for p in pList])


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1])
ax.plot(rList_01[:,0],rList_01[:,1])
ax.plot(rList_02[:,0],rList_02[:,1],linestyle="--")
ax.plot(rList_03[:,0],rList_03[:,1],linestyle="--")
ax.plot(rList_04[:,0],rList_04[:,1],linestyle="--")


plt.show()


>> [ 2.05070788  -1.12399476  11.02276442]
>> [ 2.05071109 -1.12399791  0.40958281]               11.0227695567
>> [ 3.32479577e-01   2.14732017e+00   6.60281574e+02] 8.0
>> [ 3.64934819   -4.14597378 -679.24155201]           14.0
```

If the radius is within the interval the result coincides with the simple fit. Otherwise `x` becomes a very large positive or negative number, basically meaning that `r` is one of your given limits. The nice thing is that this is continuous.

Results for the given code look like 
[image: fit]
Blue dots: random data, blue graph: simple fit, yellow graph: fit with `r` inside boundaries, green graph: fit with `r` larger than upper boundary, red graph: fit with `r` smaller than lower boundary.

Comment: I've implemented this in C++ and it seems to work reasonably well, so thank you for your answer. However, I've noticed that in some cases the fitted circle is in the wrong direction (i.e. the points are on the wrong side of the circle). This is highly affected by the choice of the estimate values. What sort of values should I be using for the estimate?

Comment: @Adrian For the `xc` and `yc` I'd use the centre of mass of your data, That should put it at least on the right side, unless if it is a straight line, in which case there is no correct side. A start value for the radius is somewhat more tricky. If you have the time to calculate it, you might use half the distance of the largest point-to-point separation. That is not very efficient, though. If you know that the arc is less than pi, and your data is ordered you might take half the distance from first to last point. I guess that should work....But `r` was fixed anyway...OK

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`HoughCircles()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles)? It lets you specify both parameters. Example taken from the linked docs, modified to add the minimum and maximum radius parameters:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat img, gray;
    img = imread('ring.png')
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // smooth it, otherwise a lot of false circles may be detected
    medianBlur(gray, gray, 7);
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    int minRadius = 90
    int maxRadius = 100
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                 1, 100, 20, 20, minRadius, maxRadius);
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
         Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
         int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
         // draw the circle center
         circle( img, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
         // draw the circle outline
         circle( img, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
    }
    namedWindow( "circles", 1 );
    imshow( "circles", img );
    return 0;
}
```

Example running (note, I made this with Python but with the same parameters):

[image: Original image]
[image: Detected circles]

Image stolen from [a PhD student at CMU](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wmartin/vision/circles.html).

Comment: I can't use HoughCircles because the image doesn't contain full circles, only arcs. I only want to fit a circle/arc to a set of points which have already gone through several processing steps.